# software analysis .... Start with UML or Design Patterns?

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml

I am a java programmer with 2 years experience, I really like programming, especially OO programming, and if I have a project, I start with programming directly, without any system analysis operations, so my code is not sorted as it should be, I want to learn how to write and design a good code, should I start learning UML or I can go directly through Design patterns ? and what are the best books for learning UML and Design Patterns.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: You talk about learning UML as if that was a huge task. The basics, which is all you really need to know, can be described in a couple of pages.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a broad-brush design, where you identify the major parts of your solution. You can use UML for that, but it's not mandatory.

Then, start writing tests, or executable specifications, and evolve the code to meet those tests. Use your broad-brush design as a guide, and also the tests. Practice test-driven development. Solicit feedback from your stakeholders. Iterate. Iterate. Iterate.

(Of course, that depends a lot on the type of application that you do, I'm assuming business-like, non-safety-critical software).

As for books, look at "Domain Driven Design" and "Growing Object Oriented Software, Guided by Tests".

Oh, and never start with design patterns...

Comment: +1 for "never start with design patterns".

Comment: +1 for "Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software" by Eric Evans.

Answer (score 1):

UML is a means to an end, and by no means the only one. Try it and see if you like it, personally I'm not too fond of it. You need to discover yourself how you want to think about and design your applications. Personally I like drawing boxes on a whiteboard.

Design patterns can be useful but they describe solutions to more specific problems. A pitfall here is that people that start off with design patterns try to apply them everywhere. They try to match a design pattern with a problem, but it should be other way around. UML and Design Patterns are in no way mutually exclusive and they don't (necessarily) serve the same purpose.

As far as design patterns are concerned, I found [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) to be a nice and easy to read book, although this is terribly subjective as I know a lot of people who really hate the writing style of the Head First books.

Answer (score 0):

UML is a way to represent a model, it's not a replacement for the model. The model can be expressed in UML, but not only in UML.
Design patterns help creating the suitable model and avoiding common mistakes. Personally, I found books by Martin Fowler and Eric Evans very useful, but I'm sure there are many other good writers as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no recipe for learning how to design code, it's about experience.

well, after 15+ years of assembly/basic/pascal/java/c/c++/C# and another gazillion languages sometimes my code is just not sorted as it should (or could be), still I'm well payed and generally considered a good programmer.

Too many reasons behind that, tight release dates, too fast evolving tech, dumb client requirements, monstrous frameworks designed only thinking about extendability (it's this even an English word) and not focusing on usabiliy.

When I start a new project, the first thing I do is have a coffee.

Then I contact the customer (or whoever will use the application) and try to get a grasp on what they really need. Understanding what the client needs is the real goal (after getting paid of course ^^)

After this, I took pencil and paper and draw, not following any standard. Boxes, circles, arrows, with notes, some kind of artistic brainstorming.

Design patterns... best way to use them is avoid them. Too often they don't match real life problems, but programmers all over the world are abusing them everywhere, yes, mainstreaming leads to that. But if you feel the absolute reason to use them, start with the GoF beast (Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software: Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson e John Vlissides).

2 years is just a small amount of time. Designing good code requires a bit more time (and of course experimenting with different languages)

Comment: Actively avoiding design patterns seems... a poor approach. Particularly considering how often they're used by default language libraries. Iterator? Observer? Template? Facade? Decorator? I don't think I've worked on a project in 25 years that didn't use most or all of those.

Comment: Avoiding design patterns because some programmers abuse them is a really bad reason. There are a lot of common problems that have been solved already. And like Dave Newton states, what to think of these patterns in a lot of frameworks? Where do you suppose Commands in WPF come from?

Comment: Don't avoid design patterns.  Do read the GoF book.  But just as having a toolbox full of the right tools doesn't automatically make you a top-notch carpenter; knowing all the design patterns doesn't make you a top-notch designer.  And just occasionally, you'll meet a problem that doesn't match any of the design patterns.

Comment: I'm curious why the downvote, though; the point that patterns may be abused is valid. (I think they're much less abused these days though, now that the fever has died.)

Comment: Well, maybe I should have say "avoid abusing of design patterns". But when I start a project, honestly I couldn't care less about design patterns, first thing is understand the requirements, implementation comes later. Designing a good application is not a matter of coding it as we like or following mainstream ideas, is a matter of providing the customer with a functional, easy to use and mainteneable thing. It's just naive thinking about writing a class hierarchy (or resorting to Patterns) just to implement "HelloWorld"

Comment: In fairness, I don't believe the OP is asking about "hello world" apps, though.

Comment: Yes it was an extremization of my thought :)

Answer (score 0):

The best book available for design patterns is the [book](http://amzn.com/0201633612) 'Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software' By the Gang of Four. The latest version of this book also includes an UML book in the package.  Together this will be a good start.

However, just implementing design patterns is wrong. When you want to learn to write and design good code, understanding when to use patterns (and when to develop your own!) is a must.